# PFFile and JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parse-platform, pubnub

In my chatting application, I'm using Parse for a user table, getting ID's, images, etc. I recently added this functionality, and I have encountered a problem. When I send a message, I create an `NSDictionary` with information about the message such as time, message, sender, sender objectId, etc. But, when I try to add the PFFile (image file) associated with the user, I get an error saying that PFFile cannot be converted to JSON (PubNub message format). How can I add PFFile as part of the `NSDictionary` used in the message to be compatible with JSON, or there might be another way.

I'm not familiar with asynchronous tasks, but in my code, I have a method `- (NSDictionary *)parseMessageToDisplay:(NSDictionary *)message {}` where the input would be message received from PubNub, and it would return a format better united to be displayed in a `UITableView`. If I added the ID of the file or user to my dictionary, how could I get my image in `UIImage` or `NSData`, and return it from my method in an `NSDictionary`. Sorry if this post seems long, just trying to provide a lot of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@danh** for this suggestion, but you really saved me. Apparently Parse creates a URL for all `PFFile`s and I can just send that URL (`NSString *`) with my `NSDictionary` to PubNub, and then in my `- (NSDictionary *)parseMessageToDisplay:(NSDictionary *)message` method just use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]];` and get data from that. **YAY! No long running confusing asynchronous tasks to made my day terrible!**

Answer (score 2):

In order to use parse.com, `PFFile` in particular, you'll probably want that `NSDictionary` to be a `PFObject` instead.  A `PFFile` reference can be saved as an attribute of a `PFObject` -- in fact that's the *only way it can be saved*.

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear, but the NSDictionary is sent to pubnub servers, where it is serialized into JSON, or JSON then pubnub, i dont really know.

Comment: So you'd like to transmit the file via pubnub?  I don't know that service.  My first idea would be to save the image (with a ref in a pfobject per my suggestion) then share the just pffile URL with the remote peer.  Your chat UI on the receiving side could present an placeholder that indicated an image is being received, then it should fetch from the url with a regular http request and present the fetched image upon completion.